# Как добавлять неограниченное количество фрагментов и сохранять их?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Помогите плз, куда хотя бы посмотреть и в какую сторону. Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку добавлять фрагменты с определенным функционалом(пусть даже одинаковым). Но постоянно с чистым шаблоном, сохранять и заново при нажатии на кнопку создавать новый  и т. д. Есть на пример список дел  и заданий, я его создал, закрыл, сохранил и надо создать новый план. И  На что обратить внимание. Подскажите плз. Спасибо
Возможно есть примеры, как это делать. Не могу найти ничего похожего.

Comment: что вы понимаете под чистым/грязным шаблоном?

Comment: Имею ввиду, что есть на пример поля, которые нужно заполнить, послу чего мы сохраняем, то что написали. Создаем новый фрагмент с тем же макетом, но чистые поля.

Comment: Просто подумайте, что бы вы сделали. Наверное, была бы кнопочка, по нажатии на которую открывалась бы активность, с помощью которой и вносились бы данные (список дел и проч.). Скорее всего, кнопочка эта была бы где-нибудь на главной странице, где располагались бы внесённые заметки (список дел и проч.). Например, можно попросить пользователя задать имя списку, и его [имя списка] отображать.

Comment: я наверно, не правильно обозначил суть )) Мне нужно создать функцию, на подобии приложения samsung notes. Там где нажимая на кнопку каждый раз добавляем новый чистый шаблон, вносим свои заметки, сохраняем

Comment: Вам не нужно сохранять или создавать неограниченное количество фрагментов, а создать только один фрагмент, сохранять же данные, которые вы вводите. Соответственно при отображении заполнять сохраненными данными один и тот же фрагмент. В сэмлах кода android studio насколько я помню есть приложение-блокнот, вы можете изучить его работу.

Comment: Так же в книге Б.Филипс "android. Программирование для профессионалов очень подробно разбирается создание приложения-записной книжки Criminal Intent. Там вы найдете ответы на все возможные вопросы по созданию подобного приложения

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду разбираться))

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно создавать кучу фрагментов. Достаточно будет 2 activity. На первой activity будет список из названий этих шаблонов. Здесь вы сможете также добавить или убрать какой то из шаблонов. При нажатии на элемент из списка должна открываться вторая activity и она должна наполнятся данными которые передает intent extras или брать из какой-то базы данных. Например: вы нажали на первый элемент списка и программа берет и достает из базы данных заметку с индексом 0 и вставляет её в текстовое поле во второй activity

Список listview:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php

Передача данных между активити - Intent extras:
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html

База данных sqlite:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php

Надеюсь мой ответ поможет вам.

Comment: Спасибо, большое за помощь. ))